strapi-plugin-import-export-entries stopped working after strapi upgraded to v4.24.4
After upgrading strapi to 4.24.4, strapi-plugin-import-export-entries plugin export has stopped working on strapi deployed on aws ecs. On localhost it works fine.


Another thing to note is deepness level 2 works but above that it fails.
Note: link for strapi-plugin-import-export-entries
https://github.com/Baboo7/strapi-plugin-import-export-entries

Not sure why this is tagged with amazon-ecs as I see absolutely nothing in the question about ECS or AWS at all.

This is something that the author of the plugin will need to fix.  But as a side note, instead of using the plugin, I use Strapi's native export and import feature.
You can export your content with the following command
  yarn strapi export --no-encrypt -f name_of_file

You can learn more here
